# A better way to use Response Cache in .net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching

I want to use `ResponseCache` on some of my endpoints.

I have added these in configuration in `appsettings.json`

```
  "CacheProfiles": {
    "MyCache": {
      "Duration": 3600,
      "Location": "Client"
    }
```

And I'm using it like below

```
 [ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "MyCache")]
 [HttpGet("user/")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> User()
  {
     // implementation
  }
```

So I have this `[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "MyCache")]` repeated in many endpoints.

so my only concern is if I have changes the profile name `MyCache` to another name.

Then I have to go through all my endpoints to update it.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: @MitchWheat I don't believe this is a good solution

Comment: Use a `const`? e.g. `MyCaches.Cache1`

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the `ResponseCache` at the controller level instead of applying it to every action method - you can override a particular action if you need to deviate from the controller level setting.

Also, you should be able to use a compile time constant to store the profile name, such as by adding this to some class:

```
public const string CacheProfile = "...";
```

Then, in your attribute tags:

```
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = SomeClass.CacheProfile)]
```

Comment: I don't want to apply ResponseCache  to the controller because not everything should be cached. And to be safe I preferred to have it on individual end point. I will use constants. Thanks!